# C# Finding the Default and Physical Printer

Tags: printing

I want to find the Physical printer marked as default. However, the Default Marked Printer must be the Physical Printer. If the default printer is a Virtual (File) printer, it should display "No Physical printer".

Note: The printer can be a Network Printer.

```
using System.Management;
class Printer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public bool Default { get; set; }
    public bool Local { get; set; }  
    public bool Network { get; set; }        
    public string PrintProcessor { get; set; }
    public string PortName { get; set; }
}

private void btnGetPrinters_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
    List<Printer> printers = new List<Models.Printer>();
    var query = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * from Win32_Printer");
    foreach (var item in query.Get())
    {
        string portName = item["PortName"].ToString().ToUpper();
        if (((bool)item["Local"]==true || (bool)item["Network"]==true) &&  (portName.StartsWith("USB") || portName.StartsWith("LPT")))
        {
            Printer p = new Models.Printer();
            p.Name = (string)item.GetPropertyValue("Name");
            p.Status = (string)item.GetPropertyValue("Status");
            p.Default = (bool)item.GetPropertyValue("Default");
            p.Local = (bool)item.GetPropertyValue("Local");
            p.Network = (bool)item.GetPropertyValue("Network");                    
            p.PrintProcessor = (string)item.GetPropertyValue("PrintProcessor");
            p.PortName = (string)item.GetPropertyValue("PortName");
            printers.Add(p);
        }
    }

    // Show on GridView 
    gv.DataSource = printers;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to find the Physical printer marked as default. However, the Default Marked Printer must be the Physical Printer. If the default printer is a Virtual (File) printer, it should display "No Physical printer".